# non-type template parameters based on hardware registers

Tags: c++, templates, stm32, non-type

I'm using the hardware timers of an STM32 to interface with a number of optical encoders.  I want to create a templatized class which provides a convenient interface for interacting with the hardware timer.  The timer registers are memory mapped and their addresses are #defined in manufacturer supplied headers that match the device datasheet.  The template parameter would effectively be the base memory address of a timer peripheral.  Below is a minimal working example of what I'm currently trying to do:

```
#include <cstdint>

// Effectively supplied by chip manufacturer headers
struct timer_peripheral {
  volatile uint32_t count;
  // ... lots of other registers ...
};
// Also supplied by chip manufacturer headers
#define TIM1 ((timer_peripheral *) 0x40000000)
#define TIM2 ((timer_peripheral *) 0x40000400)
// My templated class
template <timer_peripheral * Timer>
class OpticalEncoderCounter {
  OpticalEncoderCounter();
};

template <timer_peripheral * Timer>
OpticalEncoderCounter<Timer>::OpticalEncoderCounter()
{
}

int main()
{
  // option 1
  OpticalEncoderCounter<TIM1> encoder0;

  // option 2
  timer_peripheral * t = TIM2;
  OpticalEncoderCounter<t> encoder1;
}
```

However, when I compile, I get these errors with g++-4.7.2 -std=c++11:

error| could not convert template argument ‘1073742848u’ to ‘timer_peripheral*’

error| ‘t’ is not a valid template argument because ‘t’ is a variable, not the address of a variable

After reading around about non-type template parameters, I'm still not sure how to fix my problem and whether templates can be used the way I am thinking.  I tried static_cast and reinterpret_cast in option 1, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: This has to do with constant expressions, do you want the C++03 or the C++11 explanation?

Comment: c++11 explanation would be preferable, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### Short version

A template non-type argument has to be a constant expression. `((timer_peripheral *) 0x40000000)` includes a `reinterpret_cast` to a pointer-type, therefore you cannot use it in a constant expression.

---

#### C++03

[temp.arg.nontype]/1

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> - an integral constant-expression of integral or enumeration type; or
> - [...]
> - the address of an object or function with external linkage, including function templates and function
>     template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed as `& id-expression` where the `&` is optional if the name refers to a function or array, or if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
> - [...]

So we have to use an integral constant expression.

[expr.const]/1

> An integral constant-expression can involve only literals (2.13), enumerators, const variables or static data members of integral or enumeration types initialized with constant expressions (8.5), non-type template parameters of integral or enumeration types, and sizeof expressions. [...] **Only type conversions to integral or enumeration types can be used.**

`((timer_peripheral *) 0x40000000)` includes a cast to a pointer type, therefore it cannot appear in an integral constant expression.

---

#### C++11

[temp.arg.nontype]/1

> A template-argument for a non-type, non-template template-parameter shall be one of:
>
> - for a non-type template-parameter of integral or enumeration type, a converted constant expression (5.19) of the type of the template-parameter; or
> - [...]
> - a constant expression (5.19) that designates the address of an object with static storage duration and external or internal linkage or a function with external or internal linkage, including function templates and function template-ids but excluding non-static class members, expressed (ignoring parentheses) as `& id-expression`, except that the `&` may be omitted if the name refers to a function or array and shall be omitted if the corresponding template-parameter is a reference; or
> - [...]

We cannot use an constant expression "that designes the adress...", but could we use a converted constant expression?

[expr.const]/2

> A conditional-expression is a core constant expression unless it involves one of the following [...]
>
> - [...]
> - a reinterpret_cast (5.2.10);
> - [...]

Nope. Not possible.

---

#### A workaround

Using a function template to return the pointer.

```
#include <cstdint>

// Effectively supplied by chip manufacturer headers
struct timer_peripheral {
    volatile uint32_t count;
    // ... lots of other registers ...
};

#define TIM1 ((timer_peripheral *) 0x40000000)
#define TIM2 ((timer_peripheral *) 0x40000400)

enum TIMS { tim1, tim2 };

template < TIMS tim >
inline timer_peripheral* get_timer_address()
{
    static_assert(tim && false, "unknown timer identifier");
    return nullptr;
}
  template <>
  inline timer_peripheral* get_timer_address < tim1 >()
  {
      return TIM1;
  }
  template <>
  inline timer_peripheral* get_timer_address < tim2 >()
  {
      return TIM2;
  }

// My templated class
template < TIMS tim >
class OpticalEncoderCounter {
    static timer_peripheral* get() { return get_timer_address<tim>(); }

public:
    OpticalEncoderCounter();
};

template < TIMS tim >
OpticalEncoderCounter<tim>::OpticalEncoderCounter()
{
}

int main()
{
    OpticalEncoderCounter<tim1> encoder0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The template parameter has to be an integral type; I think the compiler is casting it to unsigned int.

You could probably make this work by running with that, and explicitly casting it yourself inside the template calss, but I don't think you need to.

Unless there is some reason you really need this to be templated, I would just either (1) add methods to the struct; or (2) create a wrapper class that just holds a pointer to the struct.

Comment: "The template parameter has to be an integral type" No. It can also be pointer, reference and some other stuff [temp.param]/4

Comment: I was originally thinking of going the wrapper class approach but was sort of hoping to avoid any runtime overhead so thought using templates would be good.  I was able to make the casting approach work, but ended up going with the wrapper class approach since the code is clearer this way and the runtime efficiency is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the pointers to constant integers using pointer arithmetic:

```
// My templated class


#define TIM_BASE TIM1

const int TIM1_OFFSET = TIM1 - TIM_BASE;

template <size_t timerOffset>
class OpticalEncoderCounter {
public:
  OpticalEncoderCounter();

  timer_peripheral * getTimer() { return  TIM_BASE + timerOffset;}

};

template <size_t timerOffset>
OpticalEncoderCounter<timerOffset>::OpticalEncoderCounter()
{

}


int main()
{

  OpticalEncoderCounter<TIM1_OFFSET> encoder0;

}
```

Comment: This still contains a `reinterpret_cast` as the macro does contain one.

Comment: The template parameter does not contain an expression with the reinterpret_cast<>; it's being hidden behind the definition of TIM1_OFFSET.

Comment: Yes, but TIM1_OFFSET then cannot be initialized at compile-time, i.e. you couldn't write `constexpr int TIM1_OFFSET = TIM1 - TIM_BASE;`

Comment: g++4.8 accepts it, but clang++ 3.0-3.2 correctly rejects it, "non-type template argument is not a constant expression"

Comment: @DyP VS2010 also accepts, but I agree your standard's references are clear. You can see that a given implementation might (strictly erroneously) elide the problem.

Comment: Did you check it doesn't just always use `0`? All kinds of weird problems could arise ;)